# How to run a normal Java Program from a Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet

I want to run a Simple java program from a Java applet. The following is the code for the program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Termi
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        String[] nu={ "xterm","-e","gedit" };
        try
        {
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(nu);
        }
        catch(Exception e){ }
    }
}
```

This is a program for opening the gedit text editor (I'm on Linux). Now, all I want to do is to execute the above program by clicking a button "Open" in an Applet. Can anybody tell me a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking you won't be able to launch an external application from an applet.  The Java sandbox in which an untrusted applet is executed is not permitted to launch external applications.

If you:

- add the required permissions to your JAR's manifest,
- signed your applet, and
- convinced the end user / browser to trust the applet.

you could potentially work around this restriction.  The following references discuss this:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html
- http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/java-7-update-51-code-signatures-required.htm
- http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

However, this presupposes that you can convince the end users (or their system admin / security staff) to enable a Java plugin at all.  A lot of people won't ... for obvious reasons.

---

IMO, you need to think of a way to edit files that doesn't involve using applets at all.

Comment: I would also suggest to forget the idea of using applets for the purpose described in the question. I would also say: think of applets as an extinct technology. Either choose server-side technologies with lightweight Webfrontend or choose a (standalone) fat client that doesn't have the restrictions of applets.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, you must rewrite java program to applet.

Comment: Ok, then how can I get the same code into an applet so that it executes when I press a button?

Comment: You want to execute jar applet?

Comment: No, just a .class applet.